# Appending fetched json data to a div

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax, fetch

I have tried to create a client side function that sends a fetch request for json data and then appends the response to a div however it doesnt seem to be working.

here is the client side function code

```
function bobFun(){ 
  
  let response = fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/dylan/list', { mode: 'no-cors' })
    .then(console.log("fetch sent"))
    //.then(console.log(response))
    .then(response => {
  return response.text().then(text => {
    document.getElementById("test").append(text)
  });
});
```

here is the server side json data

```
let dylan = ['song recommendation 1',
  'song recommendation 2',
  'song recommendation 3',
];

app.get('/dylan/list', function(req, resp){
  resp.send(dylan);
```

Comment: The argument to `.then()` needs to be a function. And if you want to chain `.then()`, that function needs to return another promise. `console.log("fetch sent")` is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is the way you're using the first `.then()`. By just console logging you're not returning a value that can be chained with the next `.then()`

See my answer below and try reformatting yours to match.

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => {
     document.getElementById("test").append(text)
  })
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not used `then` chaining correctly. In general `then` take callback function.

Below is right way of using fetch with then chaining -

```
function bobFun() {
   fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/dylan/list', {mode: 'no-cors'}).then(
     (response) => { 
       return response.text() ;
     }
   ).then( 
     (textData) => {
       document.getElementById("test").append(textData)
     }
   )
}
```

You can also use ECMAScript 2017 `async/await` instead of cumbersome `then` chaining with fetch which is having simple and clean sytanx.

```
async function bobFun() {
   const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/dylan/list', {mode: 'no-cors'})
   const textData = await response.text()
   document.getElementById("test").append(textData)
}
```